# Une suggestion avec « si + imparfait » peut-elle être également formulée avec « si + présent simple » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, conditions

La citation ci-dessous provient de la page 147 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker.

> *Si* and the *on* or *nous* form of the verb in the imperfect tense can be used as a kind of imperative to express a wish or suggestion.
>
> - Si on jouait au tennis?
>     *How about playing tennis?*
> - Si nous jouions au tennis?
>     *Suppose we play tennis?*
> - Il a une nouvelle voiture
>     *He has a new car.*
>     Si j'avais une nouvelle voiture aussi!
>     *If only I had a new car, too!*

Je ne comprends pas les différences entre l'usage de l'imparfait et du présent simple, pour manifester un vœu ou une suggestion. J'aimerais comprendre la différence entre « Si on jouait au tennis? » et « Si on joue au tennis? ». Les deux phrases sont-elles pareilles ?

Comment: Et si vous rendiez vos questions plus agréables en évitant les formules *Prière de…* ou *Veuillez faire…*, qui sont des manières de donner un ordre et non pas de poser une question?

Comment: @LaurentG : Le PO est un non francophone qui n'a visiblement du français qu'une culture livresque et de ce fait il maîtrise mal les codes de la langue. Il fait l'effort de rédiger les questions en français et peut-être ne devrions-nous pas être trop dur avec lui ?

Comment: @Laure En effet, mon but était simplement de suggérer une amélioration. À part ça, la grammaire et l'orthographe sont excellentes.

Comment: @LaurentG. Les codes du langage sont difficile à apprendre hors contexte sans corrections ou interactions. Et si nous introduisions sur fl.se les « questions et réponses modèles »  ( [*canonical posts*](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/754/2818) ) ?

Comment: En français on emploie l'imparfait pour faire une suggestion.  « Si on joue au tennis » n'exprime pas de suggestion mais une condition et on attend la fin de la phrase (« si on joue au tennis on sera fatigués » ).  « Si on jouait au tennis ? » avec un point d'interrogation exprime une suggestion, une invitation.

Comment: Méfie-toi beaucoup de cette grammaire Schaum. Ce n'est pas la première fois que je le constate. Ici il est inexact de 1) restreindre à "on" et "vous" l'expression de la suggestion. 2) il est faux de parler d'impératif ici.

Comment: @Laure: de quelle restriction parles-tu ? Autrement, il est écrit « kind of imperative » et pas « imperative », je pense que ça suffit à alerter le lecteur.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Une "sorte d'impératif" reste un impératif, soit dans le cas d'emploi, soit dans la forme, non ? La suggestion ne se forme pas comme l'impératif et n'entre pas dans les cas d'emplois de l'impératif (Grevisse défini l'impératif comme le « mode du commandement, de l'exhortation, de la prière ... il peut marquer une supposition ». AMHA l'utilisation de *kind of imperative* plutôt que d'alerter le lecteur, ne peut que l'embrouiller (encore) un plus plus.

Comment: @Laure: Je vous suis reconnaissant de votre soutien et suis en train de cherche des meilleures livres.

Comment: @LaurentG.: <s>Prière de</s> Je vous prie de bien vouloir m'excuser et de m'éclairer des maladresses ou bévues. Au demeurant, je serai reconnaissant des conseils pour l'amélioration.

Answer (score 3):

**L'imparfait de l'indicatif** peut avoir des valeurs modales et on l'emploie avec « si » pour exprimer :

- une suggestion, une invitation :

  > Et si on finissait la soirée chez moi ?

  Dans ce cas, en principe on ponctue la phrase par un point d'interrogation.
- un souhait :

  > Ah! Si tu pouvais te taire !
- un fait éventuel dans une proposition subordonnée à l'imparfait, dont la conséquence est exprimée dans la principale par un conditionnel :

  > Si on jouait au tennis, on serait fatigués.

**« Si » est suivi du présent de l'indicatif** uniquement dans une subordonnée qui exprime une condition et avec un verbe au futur dans la principale :

> S'il fait beau, je jouerai au tennis.

Comment: Merci. Pourriez-vous détailler dans votre réponse ce que signifient `des valeurs modales` dans votre 1e phrase ?

Comment: @LePressentiment. Expliquer ce qu'est un mode serait une autre question que celle à laquelle je réponds et ne serais pas une question de français mais de linguistique. Tous les livres de grammaire ont des chapitres sur le mode, sur internet, voir wikipedia, en [français](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28grammaire%29) en [anglais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood).

Comment: Merci. Je n'avais pas été sûr si le mot `mode` était un terme défini. Quelle est la différence, dans le cadre de cette question, de `condition` (dans votre phrase avant-dernière) et `des valeurs modales`? Je voudrais confirmer qu'il est erroné d'employer le présent dans les 3 cas comme indiqués avec la puce sous **L'imparfait de l'indicatif** ?

Comment: Je vous prie de répondre votre reponse propre et non pas à titre de commentaire